# Cash from the dark net?

Tags: security

Are any of these credit card sites and cash sites real?
I'd love to know some of them because I've been scrolling through websites and all I see is scam scam

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that any of them are legitimate and even if they were, you would be committing identity fraud.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what type of site your referring to. Not all are scams but as a rule if you look at a site and think it's a scam then go with that first reaction.... there is/are a  few sites where you can purchase points, play games, and win cash prizes that might seem like scams, but they are legit as far as a transaction goes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are real: as on clearnet, the Tor network *is* a "global village* where you can find all kind of stuff. They are real: sites, forums and a feed lists

Answer (score 0):

Most illegal sites on dark net are scams. If offer has no economic sense for provider (too good to be true) then it is scam.